# i create an app for notification showing but when i run the app no notifiction is pop

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
package com.example.notification;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private  static final  String CHANNEL_ID =" My channel";
    private  static final  int  NOTIFICATION_ID= 100;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Drawable drawable= ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(),R.drawable.handbag,null);
        BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable= (BitmapDrawable)drawable;
        Bitmap largeIcon = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();


        NotificationManager nm= (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            notification= new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.handbag)
                    .setContentText("new message")
                    .setSubText("new message for khan")
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .build();
            nm.createNotificationChannel((new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"New channel",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)));

        } else{
            notification= new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.handbag)
                    .setContentText("new message")
                    .setSubText("new message for khan")
                    .build();

        }
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
    }
}
```

here is the code i write

can you please tell me where my code goes wrong it have too show the notification when i open the app but no notification is there ..........................................................................................................................................

Comment: Starting with Android 13 and up. You must request runtime authorization to display a message. You must request POST_NOTIFICATIONS access.

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 8.0 and above, need to create notification channel before building a notification as follows:

```
notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(
            NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME,
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
        )
```

Read [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/channels)

From Android 13 onwards, request `POST_NOTIFICATIONS` runtime permission. Read [here](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/notification-permission)